# How to eliminate the whole number and return only the decimal digits?

Tags: java

Sample output:

[image]

I'm doing a little project on my own practicing my skills in Java and I ran into a dead end, I don't know how should I code this.

Is there a way that I could only grab the decimal digits only without the whole number from the sum of the given input by the user?

Comment: Subtract the whole number from the decimal number. What remains is the fractional part.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```java
public static double extractDecimals(double value) {
    return value - Math.floor(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    double x = 1.60714;
    int y = (int)x;
    x = (x-y)*12;
    int m = (int)x;
    x = (x-m)*30;
    int d = (int)x;
    System.out.println(y + "/" + m + "/" + d);
```